# Unable to connect to XSockets.NET server using out-of-the-box XSockets.NET C# API when transport is over WSS

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, websocket, xsockets.net

I've built a WebSockets server using XSockets.NET and I've switched it to use WSS scheme (SSL).

While it seems that JavaScript XSockets.NET API reaches the whole WebSocket server, C# API doesn't get connected.

Sample client code:

```
ClientPool notificationsPoolClient = 
    ClientPool.GetInstance("wss://[host]:7532/[controller name]", "*");
```

When I try to send a message using the whole `ClientPool` I get a `KeyNotFoundException`:

```
commentsPoolClient.Send([text], "[Action name]");
```

I've checked official XSockets.NET documentation with no luck because it's not completed in terms of consuming WebSockets from .NET using WSS scheme (SSL).

My guess is I'm not obtaining the `ClientPool` instance in the right way, but this was working until I switched to WSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted XSockets.NET team and the problem is `ClientPool` has no SSL/TSL support in 3.x branch, but they're looking to add this feature in the incoming 4.x branch.